# How to upload a new version on transferred app from other account ,Potential loss of keychain access

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, app-store-connect

I have transferred app from one account to another iTunes account.

I have created new certificate and provisioning profile from new developer account.
Now, I am trying to upload a new version of the app and getting below warning

> WARNING ITMS-90067 :Potential loss of keychain access. The previous
>   version of software has an application-identifier value of
>   [‘FKKB5B9763.com.(my-app-id)'] and the new version of software being
>   submitted has an application-identifier of [‘BBB5Y2NZ8S
>   .com.(my-app-id). This will result in a loss of keychain access.

Due to this warning, app is not uploading on iTunes.

In my case, Bundle ID is same but App ID prefix is different because app is transferred from one account to another. And I can not edit the App ID Prefix. So, the question is how a new version can be uploaded.

**I have tried to upload app multiple times using Organiser and Application Loader and getting the same warning always. And I think because of this warning build is not being upload on iTunes. So, I am not able to submit new version.**

[image]

Comment: Have you changed your id or team?

Comment: I have transferred the app from one account to another iTunes account.

Answer (score 2):

It’s a warning. Your App will lose access to the items added to the keychain by your app.

If your app is not using keychain then you don't have to worry and you can proceed with the upload.

This can't be avoided, Keychain group is tied with apple developer team id and team id changes if you transfer app to any other developer account.

Comment: I have updated question. Please see the text in Bold.

Comment: This warning won't stop you from uploading. What's the error while uploading?

Comment: It is having no error, it is having only warning. While uploading new version it  appears under the Activity > All builds and disappear once uploading process completed.

Comment: I think your app has been uploaded already... see whats the last build in activity tab in iTunesConnect

Comment: Its quite strange but It appears for a while in Activity Tab with processing status, while app is being uploaded and after refresh page it disappear from Activity Tab. And also build will not appear in new version for submission.

Comment: Thanks for help Bilal. A permission key was missing in pilist that I came to know when I got mail from apple, due to this build was disappearing once uploading process completed.